# substituting my countifs with sumproduct using TODAY() as a constriction

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a spreadsheet A5:A107 are dates and F5:Y107 are places assigned to the people in F5:Y5. The places assigned changed 2-3 times a year and a new schedule is made. I already set it up so that the newly changed schedules will automatically update in my data-extraction workbook.

My questions is: 
I used this formula, which works, but needs to much manual maintenance `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$F$5:Sheet2!$F$107,C1,Sheet2!$A$5:$A$107,"<"&TODAY())`

I want to use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$F$5:Sheet2!$Y$107=C1)*1)
```

But I am unsure how to add the `TODAY()` constriction on the dates in A5:107 with this formula, can anyone help me, please!

Answer (score 1):

Update: It seems to work with

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Sheet2!$F$5:Sheet2!$Y$107=C1)*1)*(Sheet2!$A$5:$A$107<TODAY()))
```

If anyone sees a flaw in this, please let me know!

Comment: Your Formula is perfect +1,, ☺